# Modify Fulfillment Status And Adding Tracking Information on Shopify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am attempting to update the fulfillment status to 'fulfilled' and include additional information such as the tracking number using the Shopify API.

Currently, I can modify other fields, such as note_attributes, but I'm encountering difficulties updating the fulfillment status. I'm unsure if I should be updating the order from the following URL: `https://${store}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-01/orders/${orderId}.json` or if there's another endpoint for fulfillment updates. I am also trying to create the fulfillment to this endpoint `https://${store}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/orders/${orderId}/fulfillments.json`, but I encounter an 404 error.

With this code I try to create a fulfillment, but I'm not being able to do it yet.

```
const fulfillmentData = {
          fulfillment: {
            location_id: 64283476117,
            tracking_number: trackingNumber,
            tracking_company: "Company",
            tracking_numbers: [trackingNumber],
            tracking_url: `https://company.eu/EU/en/parcel-tracking?match=${trackingNumber}`,
            tracking_urls: [`https://company.eu/EU/en/parcel-tracking?match=${trackingNumber}`],
            status: 'success',
            service: 'manual',
            line_items: currentOrder.line_items.map(item => ({ id: item.id, quantity: item.quantity }))
          },
        };

        const createFulfillmentResponse = await axios.post(
          `https://${store}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/orders/${orderId}/fulfillments.json`,
          fulfillmentData,
          {
            headers: {
              'X-Shopify-Access-Token': adminApiAccessToken,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }
        );
```

I can modify orders in this URL, but if I try to add a fulfillment, it doesn't work:
`https://${store}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/orders/${orderId}.json`

Thanks